# UIButton selector with touchUpInside is not working in nested UIViews using Swift 4

Tags: uiview, uibutton, nested, selector, swift4

Tap event is not working when I use a selector of an UIButton inside a nested UIView but if I put the UIButton with its selector out of the nested UIView (in the root view) it  recognizes the tap event and prints "TAP TAP" in the console.

I am using swift 4.

[This is the UIView that contains the login Button and it is a subview of the root view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy16H.png)

```
let blueBottomView: UIView = {
    let bv = UIView()
    bv.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyColors.Blue.Light
    return bv
}()
```

[This is the button and the tap event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkPGL.png)

```
let loginButton: UIButton = {
   let  lb = UIButton()
    lb.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
    lb.layer.borderColor = UIColor.MyColors.Yellow.Light.cgColor
    lb.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    lb.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyColors.Yellow.Light
    lb.setAttributedTitle(MyHelpers().createAttributeString(text: "Iniciar sesión", color: .white, bold: true), for: .normal)
    lb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapLoginButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    return lb
}()


@objc func tapLoginButton(){
    print("TAP TAP")
}
```

[This is the section where the button becomes a child of the nested UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oau0K.png)

```
func createView(isLogin: Bool = true){
    addSubview(logoImageView)
    addSubview(loginSwitchButton)
    addSubview(registerSwitchButton)
    addSubview(lineSwitching)

    blueBottomView.addSubview(userTextField)
    blueBottomView.addSubview(passwordTextField)
    if (isLogin){
        confirmPasswordTextField.removeFromSuperview()
        createAccountButton.removeFromSuperview()
        blueBottomView.addSubview(loginButton)
        blueBottomView.addSubview(forgotPassword)
        blueBottomView.addSubview(redesSocialesLabel)
        blueBottomView.addSubview(facebookButton)
        blueBottomView.addSubview(googleButton)
    }else{
        loginButton.removeFromSuperview()
        forgotPassword.removeFromSuperview()
        redesSocialesLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        facebookButton.removeFromSuperview()
        googleButton.removeFromSuperview()
        blueBottomView.addSubview(confirmPasswordTextField)
        blueBottomView.addSubview(createAccountButton)
    }


    addSubview(blueBottomView)

    _ =  logoImageView.anchor(centerYAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -250, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 354, heightConstant: 124)

    logoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    _ =  loginSwitchButton.anchor(logoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: frame.width/2, heightConstant: 35).first

    _ =  registerSwitchButton.anchor(logoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: frame.width/2, heightConstant: 35).first

    _ =  lineSwitching.anchor(registerSwitchButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 5)

    blueBottomView.anchorToTop(lineSwitching.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor)

    _ = userTextField.anchor(lineSwitching.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)

    _ = passwordTextField.anchor(userTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)


    if (isLogin){
        _ = loginButton.anchor(passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 82, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 82, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)

        _ = forgotPassword.anchor(loginButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 82, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 82, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)


        redesSocialesLabel.anchorWithConstantsToTop(forgotPassword.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 25, leftConstant: 16, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 16)//Margins at the left and right hand side

        redesSocialesLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        _ = facebookButton.anchor(redesSocialesLabel.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 52, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 52, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)

        _ = googleButton.anchor(facebookButton.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 52, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 52, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)
    }else{
        _ = confirmPasswordTextField.anchor(passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)

        _ = createAccountButton.anchor(confirmPasswordTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 82, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 82, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 35)

    }
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution! I changed the let definition to a lazy var and it works!

```
lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
 let  lb = UIButton()
 lb.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
 lb.layer.borderColor = UIColor.MyColors.Yellow.Light.cgColor
 lb.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
 lb.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyColors.Yellow.Light
 lb.setAttributedTitle(MyHelpers().createAttributeString(text:  "Iniciar sesión", color: .white, bold: true), for: .normal)
lb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapLoginButton), for: .touchUpInside)

return lb
}()
```